# Куда пропал кандидат от модераторов?

Tags: поддержка, выборы

Недавно стало известно, что даже действующий модератор может подать заявку на участие в выборах модераторов. Звучит странно, но тем не менее. Участник [Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf-andrei-apanasik) зарегистрировался таким кандидатом. Вот, даже скрин есть в [соответствующем вопросе на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353508/339911).

> [image: кандидат от ромбов]

А теперь его нет в [списке кандидатов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4?tab=nomination) (список вовсе сократился с 15 до 10). [Сам он не снимал свою кандидатуру](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55385471#55385471). В связи с этим возник вопрос: что же произошло на самом деле, почему участник пропал из списка кандидатов?

Comment: Западные кибератаки :)

Comment: αλεχολυτ, а ты почему не выдвинулся? За кого голосовать-то теперь?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov голосовать не за кого. Согласен. Но это значит, что новые выборы ближе, чем кажется.

Comment: Его Николай снял, он писал об в запрещённом на территории ruSO чатике :) Но снял как раз из-за тестового "выдвижения"